# Send data from CardView in RecyclerView to new fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

So I have a CardView in a RecyclerView which has some data inside it. I would like to click on a specific card and launch a new fragment that displays specific data from the data in the CardView (more details about the data in the CardView). Here is the relevant code.

I don't have the most experience in programming and Android in general, any help would be appreciated!

DetailsFragment: `

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

private CardView cardView;

private RecyclerView rv;

private List<Detail> detailList = new ArrayList<>();


public DetailsFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

    Context context = getActivity();
    cardView = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);

    final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    RVDetailAdapter adapter = new RVDetailAdapter(detailList);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();

    return rootView;

}

private void initializeData() {
    detailList = new ArrayList<>();
    //        not sure here
    detailList.add(new Detail(" "));
}

private void initializeAdapter(){
    RVDetailAdapter adapter = new RVDetailAdapter(detailList);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

RVNewsAdapater:

```
public class RVNewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVNewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

public static final String KEY_LINK ="link";

public static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Hello";
    CardView cv;
    TextView date;
    TextView link;
    TextView title;
    TextView today;


    public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        link = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.link);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        today = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.today);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Context context = view.getContext();

        Intent intent = null;

        for(int postion = 0; postion<42; postion++) {
           intent = new Intent(context, Details.class);

        }

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }



}

List<News> news;

RVNewsAdapter(List<News> news) {
    this.news = news;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public RVNewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemnewsfeed, viewGroup, false);
    NewsViewHolder nvh = new NewsViewHolder(v);
    return nvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder newsViewHolder, int i) {
    newsViewHolder.date.setText(news.get(i).date);
    newsViewHolder.link.setText(news.get(i).link);
    newsViewHolder.title.setText(news.get(i).title);
    newsViewHolder.today.setText(news.get(i).today);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (news != null) {
        return news.size();
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

RVDetailAdapter:

```
public class RVDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVDetailAdapter.DetailViewHolder> {


public static class DetailViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView link;

    public DetailViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        link = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.link);
    }
}

List<Detail> detail;

RVDetailAdapter(List<Detail> detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public RVDetailAdapter.DetailViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemnewsfeed, viewGroup, false);
    DetailViewHolder dvh = new DetailViewHolder(v);
    return dvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DetailViewHolder detailViewHolder, int i) {
    detailViewHolder.link.setText(detail.get(i).link);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (detail != null) {
        return detail.size();
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but I just saw the post and thought I'd give you one option.

When I'm using a RecyclerView (doesn't matter if it's using the CardView or not, it's the same for any list item), I create a a click listener for the view item in the Adapter.  When the user clicks the item/cardview, I dispatch an item click event.  It's your choice on how you respond - you can use a standard callback interface (and pass in your listener when you create the adapter) or use something like EventBus.

Here's an example of the code you would add to your adapter class:

```
@Override 
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {  
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            itemClick(view);
        }
    });

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}   

private void itemClick(View view) {
    //Handle item event here
    //EventBus.getDefault().post(new ItemSelectedEvent(/*send apprpopriate data*/));
}
```